# Android alarm and broadcast

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have defined my Android alarm and `BroadcastReceiver` as follows. My hope was that I want the alarm to go off two minutes later and every 15 minutes subsequently. This does not seem to be happening. Why is this?

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 2);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DailyNotificationReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);


public class DailyNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("received", "received");
        }
}
```

Comment: Your code actually sets the Alarm to be executed after every 15 minutes. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Your code looks fine, did you register your `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest?

Comment: @IonAalbers. No I didn't. I was not aware I had to do that. I'll try that and come back.

Comment: And, what is the reason for downvote ?

Comment: @Kedarnath. This can sometimes happen. Looks like there are folks who believe this is too stupid a question to be asked here. Ion Aalbers. After registering the receiver in the manifest, the code is working as intended. Thanks both of you for helping me.

Comment: @SandahAung, Just ignore them ( +1 for good question ). Good that your error solved. You can answer your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the `BroadcastReceiver` was not registered.

Please register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the `manifest`